# Excel VBA check if named range is set

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to determine if a named range has been set via VBA. The named range is called `LoadedToken` and essentially is loaded when a user clicks a particular button. I use this as proof that initialisation has taken place.

I have a function to check if this has taken place:

```
Function ToolIsEnabled()

    ' We check if the R2A add-in has been loaded by detecting the named range
    If ActiveWorkbook.Names("LoadedToken") Is Nothing Then
        ToolIsEnabled = False
    Else
        ToolIsEnabled = True
    End If

End Function
```

and I get an application error. Of course, the VBA is incorrect. However how can I actually accomplish this?!

Comment: the short version `ToolIsEnabled = [ISERR(LoadedToken)]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print IsNamedRange("Bumsti")
End Sub

Function IsNamedRange(RName As String) As Boolean
Dim N As Name

    IsNamedRange = False
    For Each N In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        If N.Name = RName Then
            IsNamedRange = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Usage in OP context could be

```
' ...
If IsNamedRange("LoadedToken") Then
    ' ...
End If
' ...
```

or - if a program specific Bool needs to be set

```
' ...
Dim IsTokenLoaded as Boolean
IsTokenLoaded = IsNamedRange("LoadedToken")
' ...
```

Both constructs make it pretty clear in the source code what you are aiming for.

Comment: Yeah, this ought to be part of a core library of extensions.  (rather than using On Error Resume Next )

Comment: Guess where it's coming from ... my core lib :-)

Comment: Very readable solution and something i've added to my little helpers class.

Comment: For me, N.Name includes sheet_name and '!' so i change MikeD 's code using inStr():

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using error handling:

```
Function ToolIsEnabled() As Boolean
    Dim rng As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Range("LoadedToken")
    On Error GoTo 0

    ToolIsEnabled = Not rng is Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

For the activeworkbook, you could also call the old XLM NAMES() function:

```
Function IsNameInActiveWorkbook(sName As String) As Boolean
    IsNameInActiveWorkbook = Not IsError(Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("MATCH(""" & sName & """,NAMES(),0)"))
End Function
```

Comment: This solution worked best for me. The error handling options broke my script. I hope they won't remove this func from Excel anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

This will check either in `ThisWorkbook` or a named workbook and return TRUE/FALSE.

```
Sub Test()

    MsgBox NamedRangeExists("SomeName")
    MsgBox NamedRangeExists("SomeOtherName", Workbooks("Book1.xls"))

End Sub

Public Function NamedRangeExists(sName As String, Optional Book As Workbook) As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next

        If Book Is Nothing Then
            Set Book = ThisWorkbook
        End If

        NamedRangeExists = Book.Names(sName).Index <> (Err.Number = 0)

    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Edit:
A shorter version if it's only going to look in `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Public Function NamedRangeExists(sName As String) As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next

        NamedRangeExists = ThisWorkbook.Names(sName).Index <> (Err.Number = 0)

    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Comment: interesting, how is the `<>` evaluated when `ThisWorkbook.Names(sName).Index` throws an error? Is is actually evaluating to `false` or is the return value just the default value of `NamedRangeExists`?

Comment: My understanding of it is that, as you say, the default value is `false` which is returned if `ThisWorkbook.Names(sName).Index <> (Err.Number = 0)` throws an error due to the name not existing.  If it does exist though it will return a positive value and `Err.Number = 0` will return TRUE which equates to -1 so the result will be something like `1 <> -1 = TRUE`

Comment: But `ThisWorkbook.Names(sName).Index > 0` would do the same thing, right?

Comment: Oh go on then.... <insert expletive> - yes it would.  You know when you copy a method that works on another similar function and don't think about  a better way of doing it....

Answer (score 0):

As per Tom's answer these 2 line should do the trick:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set TestRange = ActiveWorkbook.Range("LoadedToken")  'if it does **not** exist this line will be ERROR
```